# How to define multiple linux file paths and validate C#

Tags: c#, bdd, specflow

I've written a piece of code for my specflow 'Then' step. I understand how to read one file. But i want my code to to follow a certain path (`"/orabin/app/inputs/ff/actuals/"`) then read (Cat) multiple files. I will then validate the data against my expected data output.

The processFilePath will always be constant but the {Path} should change with the different file names.

```
.RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");



    [Then("Transfer out measure should be generated for (.*)")]

    public void ValidateInventoryMeasurement(string path, string expected)
    {
        const string processFilePath = "/orabin/app/inputs/ff/actuals/";
        var actual = Common.LinuxCommandExecutor
                           .RunLinuxcommand($"cat {processFilePath}{path}");

      //xxx_xxx.csv.ovrr, xxx.xxx.xxx.csv.ovrr
      // Multiple file name above 




        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);

    }
```

Feature file:

```
Given I Loaded Measurement in domain for Current
And interface is generated 
When batch is executed
Then Transfer out measure should be generated Current
Examples:
| Lifecyclestatus |
| PreNew          |
| New             |
| Current         |
```

Comment: How you have defined this Then in feature file?

Comment: Have you looked into using Tables in your feature file - http://toolsqa.com/specflow/tables-in-specflow/

Comment: I've pasted my feature file. All validations will occur in the then step. What i'm essentially doing is following the file path then 'Cat' the applicable files i require. Then i'll be validating it against my expected output. I'm just unsure how i would write code so i can read multiple files within my 'Then' step

Answer (score 1):

You should define the `Then` in `Steps` class as to accept 2 input parameters.

```
[Then(@"Transfer out measure (.*) should be generated as (.*)")]
public void ValidateInventoryMeasurement(string path, string expected)
```

And the feature file should define as below. The  and  defines the test input parameters.

```
Given I Loaded Measurement in domain for Current
And interface is generated 
When batch is executed
Then Transfer out measure <inputPath> should be generated as <expectedPath>
Examples:
| inputPath       | expectedPath      |
| Lifecyclestatus | placeyourvalhere  | 
| PreNew          | placeyourvalhere  | 
| New             | placeyourvalhere  | 
| Current         | placeyourvalhere  |
```

Make sure that you change `placeyourvalhere` with the expected value as per input.

Comment: Hi, instead of having it as an extra parameter. Can i code it so that in my 'Then' step i'm defining the file path and my expected output

Comment: So for example have it as file name xxx_xxx.csv.ovr, xxx_xxx.csv.ovrr, xxx_xxx.csv.ovrr. Then expected result '333','333',555'.

Comment: Use you can string manipulation like sending a string with delimeter. And in your steps method then Then will have one parameter and while split the string based on delimiter..... That being said, I think, it's not a good approach. The test should be written in such a way that it works based on input and expected parameters. So I would suggest to go with two parameters approach as suggested in my answer.

Comment: So for example would it be string path = 'xxx_xxx.csv.ovr, xxx_xxx.csv.ovrr, xxx_xxx.csv.ovrr'. And string expected '333','333','555'.

Comment: You should write a test which takes an input and expect an output. As mentioned earlier, you can pass delimiter separated input and output but it would make your code more clumsy as you have to work on string manipulation. It's better send an input and exepct an output for it.